# Gaussian Prime must have size $p$ or $p^2$

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization, gaussian-integers

Chapter 38 of Mazur and Stein's *"Prime Numbers and the Riemann Hypothesis"* asks us to prove that if a Gaussian integer is a prime Gaussian integer, then its norm can only be an "ordinary prime number, or the square of an ordinary prime number".

$$|G_{\text{prime}}|=p \text{ or } p^2 $$

I have researched other questions and answers on this site and via google but cannot find a simple explanation that I can understand.

I'd appreciate an answer that avoids too much terminology. For example, this answer is not clear enough for me as someone not formally trained in mathematics: [Problem about Gaussian prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3201558/problem-about-gaussian-prime)

Note: the system suggests this is answered here, but the answer doesn't meet the request here for a accessibility to those without formal mathematics training: [The norm of a Gaussian prime is a prime or a square of a prime in $\mathbb{Z}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1640798/the-norm-of-a-gaussian-prime-is-a-prime-or-a-square-of-a-prime-in-mathbbz)

Comment: Let $\pi$ be a Gaussian prime. Its norm ${\rm N}(\pi) = \pi\overline{\pi}$ is a positive integer greater than $1$. Factor this into a product of ordinary prime numbers, say $p_1p_2\cdots p_r$. Since $\pi$ is a factor of ${\rm N}(\pi)$, $\pi$ is a factor of $p_1p_2\cdots p_r$. Thus, since $\pi$ is *prime*, $\pi$ is a factor of some $p_i$. Therefore the positive integer ${\rm N}(\pi)$ is a factor of ${\rm N}(p_i) = p_i^2$, so ${\rm N}(\pi)$ is $p_i$ or $p_i^2$ (the norm is bigger than $1$).

Comment: @KCd your comment should be an answer. It's complete and directly address the question.

Comment: @JCAA thanks but sadly I am unable to follow that suggested answer.

Comment: Then you should ask questions to the person who answered that question.

Comment: @KCd - I am almost there with your explanation, but not quite. You say that since $\pi$ is prime, it is also a factor of some $p_i$. Why is this? Why can't $\pi$ be a factor of several of the primes in the factorisation of $N(\pi)$? If I assume you are correct, and $\pi$ is a factor of only one of those primes $p_i$, then why is $N(\pi)$ a factor of $N({p_i})$?

Comment: It is irrelevant if $\pi$ is a factor of several $p_i$: where is it ever mentioned that it couldn't divide more than one? I don't know why you're focusing on "only one" when that has no role anywhere in what I wrote. In $\mathbf Z$, if $2 \mid a_1a_2\cdots a_r$ then $2 \mid a_i$ for some $i$. Can it divide more than one $a_i$? Of course, but who cares? It divides some $a_i$ (maybe more than one, whatever) and that's good enough.